# PHP variables inside textarea

Tags: php, variables

My code:

```
foreach($usernames as $u){
    $body=$_POST['message']; //$_POST['message']="Hi,$u[name]";
   echo $body;
}
```

I want it to echo "Hi!xyz" bt its printing "Hi!$u[name]"

Comment: What is the content of the $usernames variable?

Comment: Variable parsing does only work if you *create* the string. Besides that, you don't want to give the user access to your variables this way.

Comment: its an array containing names

Answer (score 3):

Submitting some PHP code from a form will not magically make PHP execute that code. You cannot ever make your code, as written, convert that $u[name] in the form data into whatever its value should be, without a lot of extra work.

To do the variabl replacement, you have to use `eval()`, and this opens up a huge security hole on your server. You'd be executing code provided by a remote user, and they can submit anything they want. It's the equivalent of handing the keys to your car over to a random stranger and hoping they won't run over anyone on the to robbing a bank.